# What does a "set+0" in an SQL statement do?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm baffled as to what this SQL statement means:

```
SELECT exhibitor_categories+0 from exhibitor_registry
```

What is exhibitor_categories+0 ? It returns a number for each row returned.

exhibitor_categories is defined as:

```
set('contemporary', 'classical impression / transitional', 'outdoor', 'home accessories')
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: +1  Nice question.  I wonder if there is an equivalent for SQL Server 200/2005?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It implicity converts the set value to an `INTEGER`.

A set is treated as a bitmap, so the first value sets bit `0`, the second value sets bit `1` etc.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE exhibitor_registry(exhibitor_categories set('contemporary',
'classical impression / transitional', 'outdoor', 'home accessories') NOT NULL);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT
    -> INTO    exhibitor_registry
    -> VALUES  ('contemporary,classical impression / transitional,outdoor');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT  exhibitor_categories
    -> FROM    exhibitor_registry;
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| exhibitor_categories                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| contemporary,classical impression / transitional,outdoor |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT  exhibitor_categories + 0
    -> FROM    exhibitor_registry;
+--------------------------+
| exhibitor_categories + 0 |
+--------------------------+
|                        7 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: for example, how is a value like "contemporary" converted into an integer? or, since it's a set, how is "contemporary,outdoor" converted into an integer?

do you have any insights as to the purpose of converting a set value into an integer?

Comment: wow! very helpful!
how did it become 7 though? wouldn't it be 6 because 1+2+3  = 6 ?

Comment: `@Obay`: a bitmap adds powers of two so they don't get mixed. It's `2^0` + 2^1 + `2^2 = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7`. With `6`, you wouldn't be able to distinguish between, say, `1 + 2 + 3` and `2 + 4`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html for the full skinny, but basically a field like that is known as an 'set' - it has a list of possible values, which can only be one or more of those.  The value is stored as a number... which means the exhibitor_categories is actually storing the value 4 when someone sets the value to 'outdoor', because it's setting the third bit - '0100'.  When you get the value back out of the database later, mysql automatically turns '0100' back into 'outdoor' for you.

But, by adding +0 to the query, you force the result to stay a number, so you would actually get the number value '0100' if the row's value was set to 'outdoor' in this case.

*Apologies for getting enum and set mixed up.*

Why, you might ask, is it setting the value to '0100' instead of just saying '3', like in an enum?  Because a set can hold multiple values - if the values 'contemporary' (0001) and 'outdoor' (0100) were selected, it would store '0101' <- setting the 1st and 3rd bits, which would be returned as '5' if you use the +0 code.

Comment: This is a `set` (bitmap), not an `enum`. Storing `outdoor` will set the numerical value to `4`.

Comment: Quassnoi, why 4? Wouldn't it be 3 since it's the third element declared?